# Best practice to create a SOAP envelope in code?

Tags: xml, typescript, express, soap, nodes

I have a big SOAP envelop body.

Its values are accumulated in 3 different models populated from user inputs, during my applications form journey.

I am using MEAN stack (Mongo Express Nodejs) ..typescript is the language

***What should be the best way to build up this XML***, which is to be passed as SOAP requests's body

- should this be made programatically, then kindly suggest a library
- should I be using concat of string to get this done
- any other way ? like storing a raw format in some template file

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:b2b="http://www.abcd.com/B2BService" xmlns:pol="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Policy" xmlns:ser="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <b2b:IssuePolicy>
         <b2b:PolicyIssuanceRequest>
            <pol:PaymentDetails>
               <ser:ApplicationDetails>
                  <ser:PartnerApplicationDetails>
                     <ser:Amount>30887</ser:Amount>
                     <ser:ApplicationNumber>B11944</ser:ApplicationNumber>
                     <ser:BusinessType>1</ser:BusinessType>
                     <ser:ProductCode>11006</ser:ProductCode>
                     <ser:ProposalNumber>117944P</ser:ProposalNumber>
                  </ser:PartnerApplicationDetails>                  
               </ser:ApplicationDetails>
               <ser:BankCode>4502</ser:BankCode>
               <ser:BankRefNo>20227141272095</ser:BankRefNo>
               <ser:CardHolderName>Amit</ser:CardHolderName>
               <ser:ChildID>123</ser:ChildID>
               <ser:CrossSellCommonCode>No</ser:CrossSellCommonCode>
               <ser:CustomerEmail>amit@gmail.com</ser:CustomerEmail>
               <ser:CustomerName>Amit</ser:CustomerName>
               <ser:DateofReceipt>2020-08-14</ser:DateofReceipt>
               <ser:EduCess>0</ser:EduCess>
               <ser:GrossTxnAmount>30887</ser:GrossTxnAmount>
               <ser:HigherEduCess>0</ser:HigherEduCess>
               <ser:InsuredName>Sunil Kumar</ser:InsuredName>
               <ser:NetAmountPaid>30887</ser:NetAmountPaid>
               <ser:PGType>Paytm</ser:PGType>
               <ser:ParentID>PG21967</ser:ParentID>
               <ser:PaymentNumber>1234</ser:PaymentNumber>
               <ser:PaymentType>EMI</ser:PaymentType>
               <ser:ServiceTax>0</ser:ServiceTax>
            </pol:PaymentDetails>
         </b2b:PolicyIssuanceRequest>
      </b2b:IssuePolicy>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @jdweng Typescript (Express framework)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Net code for serializing :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string soap = File.ReadAllText(INPUT_FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(soap);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);

            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            namespaces.Add("b2b", "http://www.abcd.com/B2BService");
            namespaces.Add("ser", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects");
            namespaces.Add("pol", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Policy");

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME, settings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, envelope, namespaces);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }
    public class Header
    {
    }
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "IssuePolicy", Namespace = "http://www.abcd.com/B2BService")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "PolicyIssuanceRequest", Namespace = "http://www.abcd.com/B2BService")]
        public List<Policy> Policy { get; set; }
    }
    public class Policy
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PaymentDetails", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Policy")]
        public Payment Payment { get; set; }
    }
    public class Payment
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "ApplicationDetails", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "PartnerApplicationDetails", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public List<Application> Application { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public int BankCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public long BankRefNo { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public string CardHolderName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public int ChildID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public string CrossSellCommonCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public DateTime DateofReceipt { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public int EduCess { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public int GrossTxnAmount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public int HigherEduCess { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public string InsuredName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public int NetAmountPaid { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public string PGType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public string ParentID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public int PaymentNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public string PaymentType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceObjects")]
        public int ServiceTax { get; set; }
    }
    public class Application
    {
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationNumber { get; set; }
        public int BusinessType { get; set; }
        public int ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string ProposalNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```